# Raspberry Pi: Does the framebuffer image viewer (FBI) display gifs?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, framebuffer

I have a TFT Screen hooked up to a Raspberry Pi. When I tried to display a gif using fbi, it just showed a static image. Does it only work for images?

If so, what can I use instead to display gifs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Images. It will sometimes show a gif but not animate it.
from [fbi's man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/fbi.1.html)

> fbi  displays  the  specified  file(s)  on  the linux console using the
>           framebuffer device.  PhotoCD, jpeg, ppm, gif, tiff, xwd,  bmp  and  png
>           are  supported  directly.  For other formats fbi tries to use ImageMag‐
>           ick’s convert.

You can use mplayer for playing gifs